# Handlebars subexpression throws "options.fn is not a function" error

Tags: javascript, handlebars.js, handlebarshelper

I'm trying to use subexpression in Handlebars but getting "options.fn is not a function" error even on simplest expression. While using additional helpers from https://github.com/assemble/handlebars-helpers, this expression works fine:

```
{{#and true true}}OK{{/and}}
```

But if I make a subexpression like this

```
{{#and (gt 4 3) (gt 5 4)}}OK{{/and}}
```

Or this

```
{{#and (gt 4 3) true}}OK{{/and}}
```

The library throws an error

> TypeError: [feed.hbs] options.fn is not a function
>     at Object.helpers.gt (/Users/me/Projects/jackal/node_modules/handlebars-helpers/lib/comparison.js:152:20)
>     at Object.eval (eval at createFunctionContext ...

I need to have a check for two conditions. At this time it achieved with nested expressions:

```
{{#gt 4 3}}
    {{#gt 5 4}}
        ok
    {{/gt}}
{{/gt}}
```

So whats wrong with my subexpressions?

Comment: In the docs of [`handlebars-helpers`](https://github.com/assemble/handlebars-helpers), I can't see that they mention subexpressions anywhere. Where did you see that you can use subexpressions?

Comment: http://handlebarsjs.com/expressions.html here

Comment: I created an issue referencing your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To me it looks like that *subexpressions*  are not supported by `handlebars-helpers` that way.

I had a short look at at the code with the debugger. For the `{{#and (gt 4 3) (gt 5 4)}}OK{{/and}}` and the `(gt 4 3)` itself is called correctly, but the code of the `gt` helper is:

```
helpers.gt = function(a, b, options) {
  if (arguments.length === 2) {
    options = b;
    b = options.hash.compare;
  }
  if (a > b) {
    return options.fn(this);
  }
  return options.inverse(this);
};
```

But because subexpressions do neither have a `fn` (if block), nor a `inverse` (else block), the `handlebars-helpers` fails at this point.

To support your expression the `handlebars-helpers` need - IMHO -  rewrite their code to something like that:

```
helpers.gt = function(a, b, options) {
  if (arguments.length === 2) {
    options = b;
    b = options.hash.compare;
  }

  //fn block exists to it is not a subexpression

  if( options.fn ) {
     if (a > b) {
       return options.fn(this);
     }
     return options.inverse(this);
  } else {
     return a > b;
  }
};
```

So for now you can't use subexpressions with `handlebars-helpers`.

I added an Issue on their github page: [Supporting Handlebars subexpressions](https://github.com/assemble/handlebars-helpers/issues/224)